# Django: How to filter property through ORM or Mysql?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, orm

model:

```
class Production(models.Model):
    copy = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def num(self):
        n = 0
        if self.copy:
            n += 1
            n += self.copy.num
        return n
```

I want to filter out data that has been copied more than 2 times. But my approach is too slow.

```
qs = [q for q in Production.objects.filter(copy__isnull=False) if q.num > 2]
```

Is it possible to use ORM or MySQL?

Comment: Try `Production.objects.filter(copy__isnull=False, copy__copy__isnull=False, copy__copy__copy__isnull=False)`? If this does work it still is not a great query as it joins on itself 4 times. Perhaps you should just store `num` as a field instead? (might lead to inconsistent data but still better than such big joins)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat This is useful. I will consider your suggestions, thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe, to materialize aggregate counts on each model is a better solution. You can override `save` method to keep aggregate_count up to date.

Comment: @daniherrera Great idea, thanks.

Comment: @Scheinin, do you need me to post it as solution? (documented)

Comment: @danihera That's great! It's very kind of you!